# Converting a function from SQL Server to MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba

I have some code designed to interpolate values in a table, written in SQL Server:

Create table/build schema:

```
  CREATE TABLE Inter
    ([id] int, [MarkDate] date, [MaturityDate] date, [ZeroRate] int)
;

INSERT INTO Inter
    ([id], [MarkDate], [MaturityDate], [ZeroRate])

VALUES
    (1, '2015-07-02', '2015-07-02', 1),
    (2, '2015-07-02', '2015-07-03', 5),
    (3, '2015-07-02', '2015-07-06', 15)
;


CREATE TABLE allDates
    ([id] int, [MaturityDate] date)
;

INSERT INTO allDates
    ([id], [MaturityDate])

VALUES
    (1, '2015-07-01'),
    (2, '2015-07-02'),
    (3, '2015-07-03'),
    (4, '2015-07-04'),
    (5, '2015-07-05'),
    (6, '2015-07-06'),
    (7, '2015-07-07'),
    (8, '2015-07-08'),
    (9, '2015-07-09')
;

CREATE TABLE rangesInter
    ([id] int, [MarkDate] date, [begindate] date, [enddate] date, startRate float, rateChange float);


INSERT INTO rangesInter
    SELECT 
        I1.id, 
        I1.[MarkDate], 
        I1.[MaturityDate] begindate, 
        I2.[MaturityDate] enddate, 
        I1.[ZeroRate] startRate,
        (I2.ZeroRate - I1.ZeroRate) * 1.0 / DATEDIFF ( day , I1.[MaturityDate], I2.[MaturityDate] )  rateChange        
    FROM Inter I1
    inner join Inter I2
    on I1.id = I2.id - 1;
```

Interpolate values:

```
SELECT 
    IIF(i.MarkDate IS NULL, r.MarkDate, i.MarkDate) as MarkDate,
    a.MaturityDate,
    IIF(i.ZeroRate IS NULL,
           r.startRate + DATEDIFF ( day , r.begindate, a.MaturityDate ) * rateChange,
           i.ZeroRate) as ZeroRate,
    i.*, r.*
FROM  
    allDates a
LEFT JOIN 
    Inter I ON a.MaturityDate  = I.MaturityDate
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
         MIN(MaturityDate) minDate, MAX(MaturityDate) maxDate
     FROM Inter) AS t
LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT 
         I1.id, I1.[MarkDate], 
         I1.[MaturityDate] begindate, I2.[MaturityDate] enddate, 
         I1.[ZeroRate] startRate,
         (I2.ZeroRate - I1.ZeroRate) * 1.0 / DATEDIFF ( day , I1.[MaturityDate], I2.[MaturityDate] )  rateChange        
     FROM 
         Inter I1
     INNER JOIN
         Inter I2 ON I1.id = I2.id - 1) r ON a.MaturityDate > r.[begindate]
                                          AND a.MaturityDate < r.[enddate] 
WHERE
    a.MaturityDate >= t.minDate
    AND a.MaturityDate <= t.maxDate;
```

How would I go about converting this code to MS Access VBA?

I am not sure how to begin converting the "interpolate values" part of the code to work with Access VBA.

Comment: Looks legit to me.  Did you actually try running that code in Access?  Did it give you any specific errors?  If anything, I'd think it wouldn't work the other way around; I thought you needed CASE WHEN statements instead of IIF in SQL Server.

Comment: When writing code in VBA you will find the technique outlined in this answer helps you simplify and SQL strings you build in VBA See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684546/how-to-format-a-sql-string-into-a-readable-block-of-code-that-is-well-formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interested to know why you are converting this to be in access VBA.

I would build the query SQL as a string in VBA and then create a QueryDef object from the SQL string.

When building the SQL string you will find the technique outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684546/how-to-format-a-sql-string-into-a-readable-block-of-code-that-is-well-formatted) answer helps you.

Some more practical points show in the SQL below:

Remove the cartesian join, explicitly in your code as below.

All column aliases and table aliases need an "AS"

Instead of IIF  you could use

```
nz(MyFieldWithNulls, AnotherfieldToBeUsedWhenItisNull)
```

Replace datediff as shown

```
SELECT Nz(i.MarkDate, r.MarkDate) as MarkDate
     , a.MaturityDate
     , Nz(i.ZeroRate 
        , r.startRate + Cint(a.MaturityDate - r.begindate) * rateChange
         ) as ZeroRate
    , i.*
    , r.*
FROM (  ( SELECT allDates.* 
            FROM allDates   
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(MaturityDate) AS minDate
                                  , MAX(MaturityDate) AS maxDate
                               FROM Inter
                            ) AS Inter
                         ON ( allDates.MaturityDate >= Inter.minDate
                              AND 
                              allDates.MaturityDate <= Inter.maxDate
                            )
        ) AS a
       LEFT JOIN Inter AS I 
              ON a.MaturityDate  = I.MaturityDate
     )
     LEFT JOIN ( SELECT , I1.id
                        , I1.[MarkDate] 
                        , I1.[MaturityDate] AS begindate
                        , I2.[MaturityDate] AS enddate, 
                        , I1.[ZeroRate]     AS startRate,
                        , (I2.ZeroRate - I1.ZeroRate) * 1.0 
                          / DATEDIFF ( day , I1.[MaturityDate], I2.[MaturityDate] )  
                          AS rateChange        
                   FROM Inter I1
                        INNER JOIN Inter I2 
                                ON I1.id = (I2.id - 1)
                ) AS r 
            ON ( a.MaturityDate > r.[begindate]
                 AND 
                 a.MaturityDate < r.[enddate] 
               )     
    ;
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. what is the advantage of using "nz" instead of IIF, since IIF already exists in MS access?

Comment: It's a simpler syntax that invovles less typing.  I suspect it may also be quicker.

Comment: I used the "aa" procedure you linked to in order to build the SQL string, but what do I need to do create the relevant QueryDef object - I am trying to follow [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177500(v=office.12).aspx) but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This might be more useful.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195966.aspx  Just don't delete it once it's created.

Answer (score 2):

A few points to get you started:

`IIf` exists in Access already, so no need to change that.

The `CROSS JOIN` keyword doesn't exist in Access; use a comma (`,`) between table names/subqueries to return a Cartesian product.  You may also need to move your `ON` statement referring to the Cartesian product into the `WHERE` clause.

When you have multiple items in an `ON` clause in Access, they need to be surrounded by parenthesis. e.g.:

```
... ON (f1.ID = f2.ID AND f1.Name = f3.Name) ...
```

Also, when you join more than one table in an Access  SQL statement, each must be surrounded by parenthesis. e.g.:

```
SELECT ...
FROM 
    ((Table1 t1 
      INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID)
      INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.ID = t3.ID)
      INNER JOIN Table4 t4 ON t1.ID = t4.ID
```

You may get errors when mixing join types in a single query (e.g. Cartesian, left and inner). If so, I would advise breaking up the query into several Access queries with similar join types in each, and then joining those parts together in another query. Breaking down the problem may also help you simplify the transition from SQL Server.

Access also has a `DateDiff` function similar to SQL Server's.  However, the first parameter is a string that represents the interval (e.g. day = "d", month = "m", etc.).  So you can replace your `DATEDIFF` function like so:

```
DateDiff("d", I1.[MaturityDate], I2.[MaturityDate])
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. do you have any suggestions for how to recreate the first part of the code where I build the table? "CREATE TABLE" should work in Access so I had thought I wouldn't have to change the code, but it does not appear to work.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statements worked for me, but keep in mind that in Access you can only do one statement per query.  Try putting the `CREATE TABLE ... ;` in its own query.  The `INSERT` must be in a separate query. Also, in Access, you can't use multiple `VALUES` for an `INSERT` statement all at once.  You can only insert one row per statement.  One way to deal with that limitation is to create a VBA statement to do all of your inserts.

Comment: Another suggestion - what I like to do is number my Access queries (e.g. "01 Create Table", "02 Insert Data into Table", etc...) Then you can run a VBA method to run all of the queries at once, such as [this one](http://fieldeffect.info/wp/frontpage/vba_library/#Run_Numbered_Queries_in_an_Access_Database).