# Hints to determine which combo boxes were selected?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 8 combo boxes in an Access database. Each combo box can either *have* a value or *not have* a value (2 options). In total, there can be 256 combinations (2^8). I am trying to create some code in VBA that loops through these combinations to determine which combination currently exists, with the ultimate goal of writing an SQL query within VBA based on that combination. So for example, let's say combo1 and combo2 both have selections, but not combo3 through combo8. If that *is* the combination I would like my SQL query to do a SELECT FROM query WHERE a column in db = combo1 and a column in db = combo2. Can anyone provide hints as to how I would structure my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim where_condtion as String
Dim sqlquery as String

where_condtion = ""

IF combo1 <>"" then
    where_condtion = where_condtion + "~fieldname~ = " & combo1
End IF
IF combo2 <>"" then
    where_condtion = where_condtion + "AND ~fieldname~ = " & combo2
End IF
*
*
*
IF combo8 <>"" then
    where_condtion = where_condtion + "AND ~fieldname~ =" & combo8
End IF

IF where_condtion <> "" then
    sqlquery = "Select * from ~table name~ where" + where_condtion
ELSE
    sqlquery = "Select * from ~table name~
End IF

sqlquery = Replace(sqlquery, "where AND ", "where ")

DoCmd.OpenQuery "sqlquery", acViewNormal, acEdit

OR

CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("sqlquery")
```

Comment: Does that evaluate multiple combinations? For example, if combo1, combo3, and combo7 <> ""

Comment: Yes, It checks all the conditions. You have to write 5 more if condition the remaining combo box like I did for 'combo box 2'

Comment: OK, I think I understand. Thank you.

Comment: This will break if combo1="" and e.g. combo2<>"" - it will create an invalid WHERE clause. See the "WHERE 1=1" trick in HarveyFrench's answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer. This problem will not occur now.

Comment: You should also add the missing quotes.

Comment: Also change `where_condtion = "~fieldname~" = combo1` to `where_condtion = "~fieldname~=" & combo1`

Comment: The above code will fail if combo 1 is equal to "" and others are not.

Comment: Which will work as long as field name do not begin with AND

Comment: There are still missing quotes by the way.

Comment: How would I execute the SQL script?

Comment: @AmitRaj - I tried the sqlquery = Replace(sqlquery,"Where AND ", "Where ") however, the code does not run. Do you have an idea why this might be?

Comment: @Chris2015  please add this part of code in  the question.

Comment: If combo_condition <> "" Then
        sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM HRBI WHERE" + combo_condition
    Else
        sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM HRBI"
    End If

sqlquery = Replace(sqlquery, "WHERE AND ", "WHERE ")

Comment: I tried modifying using ListIndex, but I'm not sure I using those correctly.

Comment: If Combo4 <> "" And Me.Combo4.ListIndex > 0 Then
    combo_condition = combo_condition + " AND HRBI.PayGroupCountryDesc = '" & Combo4 & "'"
ElseIf Combo4 <> "" And Me.Combo4.ListIndex < 0 Then
    combo_condition = combo_condition + " HRBI.PayGroupCountryDesc = '" & Combo4 & "'"
End If

Comment: I was able to figure out a way to correct my problem. I used IF statments and the ListIndex to determine if the preceding comboboxes had a value. Depending on which comboboxes if prior comboboxes had a value I knew when or when not to use AND. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim a as string, b as string 
const myAND as string = "AND "

a = ""
a = "SELECT * FROM a table "

b = ""
if cbo1.value <> "" then
  b = b & myAND & "AND field1 = '" & cbo1.value & "'"
end if

if cbo2.value <> "" then
  b = b & myAND & "field2 = '" & cbo2.value & "'"
end if

etc for each cbo box

If b <> "" Then

   ' Lazy way 
   ' a = a & "WHERE 1=1 " & b 

   ' remove the first AND way
   a = a & "WHERE 1=1 " & mid(b,len(myAND))

End if

' a now contains the SQL you need.
```

Comment: Does that evaluate multiple combinations? For example, if combo1, combo3, and combo 7 <> ""

Comment: yes.  Slightly concerned you are asking this as the code is very simple.

Comment: `a = a & "WHERE 1=1 " & b`THIS IS GREAT I like that

Comment: What does "WHERE 1=1 " mean?

Comment: @Chris2015 When none of the combo box is selected he puts a condition which always true.

Comment: Also it solves the "WHERE AND" problem in a really elegant way

Comment: Thanks. You may also like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31684546/how-to-format-a-sql-string-into-a-readable-block-of-code-that-is-well-formatted

Comment: The SQL engine will simply ignore the 1=1 and it does not impact performance.  However, I've edited my answer to be less lazy.

Comment: This is a very useful lesson/link. GREAT! THX.

Comment: How do you execute the SQL? Thanks.

Comment: @Chris2015  You have a lot of learning to do.  See th yutube or buy a book: https://www.youtube.com/user/ProgrammingMadeEZ

Comment: It becomes more than hint :)

Comment: @Amit   I though it would.

Answer (score 0):

Am option would be a concatenated string

Code Example

```
Dim strSQL as String
'basic string
strSQL = "SELECT tbl.fieldA, tbl.fieldB FROM tbl "

Dim strSQLwhere as String
strSQLwhere = ""
'Combobox cmbbox1
If Not isNull(cmbbox1) And cmbbox1.ListIndex <> -1 then
    strSQLwhere = strSQLwhere & "tbl.fieldToFilter1=" & cmbbox1
End if

'Combobox cmbbox2
If Not isNull(cmbbox2) And cmbbox2.ListIndex <> -1 then
    iF NOT strSQLwhere = "" then     
       strSQLwhere = strSQLwhere & " AND "
    end if
    strSQLwhere = strSQLwhere & "tbl.fieldToFilter2=" & cmbbox2
End if

'And so on until cmbBox 8

'Combine all Strings
if not strSQLwhere = "" then
    strSQL  = strSQL  & " WHERE (" & strSQLwhere & ")"
End if

'Add here further thing like ORDER BY, GROUP BY
'Show SQL sting if it is well fomratted, change string concatenation if not
debug.print strSQL
```

You could do the combobox if-then-(else) cases in a separate function if you are able to do that in VBA.

Comment: Wow, three similar answers... Nice to see directly other ways to Rome